# When was the last time that the Cabinet Secretary was a Privy Counsellor?

Tags: united-kingdom, civil-service

Simon Case, the British Cabinet Secretary (most senior civil servant) was appointed to the Privy Council on 13 September 2022.

Has it ever happened before that a serving cabinet secretary was a member of the privy council? If so, when was the last time?

Comment: The privy council is *mostly* a cipher, but it has certain effects. Some actions require a quorum of three, for instance. This might have been done for continuity of government reasons (!)

Comment: It's hard to put such a simple concept in adult terms, Tell.

Yes, the Privy Council is mostly a cipher… until it matters which, happily, it never has.

Even then, Rich, the Privy Council has no "effects" though it does have vital powers and so what?

When last a Cabinet Secretary was a Privy Counsellor is a matter of record.

If your search engine of choice failed to Answer your Question, that might be a matter for Stack Exchange.

That being stated in SE's guidelines, where did your search engine of choice let you down?

Comment: The Privy Council is certainly on-topic as a body with some legislative and administrative powers within the UK's political system. But being not "useful" is grounds for voting down, if you think a question is trivia. (Why Case was appointed might be more relevant, but [it is not unknown](https://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/CBP-7460/CBP-7460.pdf) for experts to be admitted to the privy council so they can view privileged information and advise on specific topics, so there's nothing odd or unconstitutional going on here.)

Comment: @Robbie - There is no need to post about your difficulty in putting across a concept in adult terms. I could lecture you about the PC but won't, except to mention that after a person is appointed to the PC they have direct access to the monarch and some still carry an ivory pass called "the ivory" to prove said entitlement. I have no idea whether that fact is made easily available by any company that currently offers a websearch service. It may well not be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last time this was the case was in 1972, when Sir Burke Trend - then Cabinet Secretary for Ted Heath - became a Privy Counsellor. His appointment was published in the [London Gazette](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/45678/supplement/6255) on May 23rd, 1972, and he remained Cabinet Secretary until 1973.